# Kernel of $f\mapsto f + \int f$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following linear opearator

$$O: C[0,1] \to C[0,1], \ \ \ Of(x) = f(x) + \int_{0}^{x} f(s)\, ds,\ x \in [0,1].$$

I want to prove that that $\ker(O)=\{0\}$. I tried to match the function to zero.

The solution of the differential equation may be 
$$y(x)=Ce^{-t},\:\; C \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Anyone can help here or give a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f \in C[0,1]$ with $Of = 0$. Then \begin{equation}
f(x) + \int_0^x f(s) \text{ }ds = 0 \Leftrightarrow f(x) = - \int_0^x f(s) \text{ }ds 
\end{equation} 
for all $x \in [0,1]$. If you don't see it by now, you may differentiate and obtain $f' = -f$ leading to the unqiue solution $f(x) = f(0)e^{-x}, x \in [0,1].$ Since $0 = (Of)(0) = f(0)$, we may conclude $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Actually, differentiation is not permitted here since you're working on $C[0,1]$ rather than $C^1[0,1]$, isn't it?

Comment: It is permitted since the right side of the equivalence tells you that f ist differentiable.

Comment: in this case it is permitted

Comment: Of course, you're completely right, sorry 'bout that...

Answer (score 6):

No need for any fancy differential equation stuff.

Suppose $Of=0$, then
$f(x) = - \int_0^x f(t) dt$ and so $|f(x)| \le x \|f\|$. Using the equality again
we get $|f(x)| \le \int_0^x t \|f\| dt = {x^2 \over 2} \|f\|$ which gives
$\|f\| \le {1 \over 2} \|f\|$ and hence $f=0$.

Comment: I think u meant $f(x) = - \int_0^x f(s) ds$ and $|f(x)| \le \int_0^x s \|f\| ds = {x^2 \over 2} \|f\|$

Comment: @Johnny_Vz: No, I meant to write $t$. In any event, the particular variable used is irrelevant other than not being $x$.