# Show this bounded linear operator is injective

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X=C([0,1])$ with the $\sup$ norm and let $T: X \to X$ given by
$$
Tf(t) = f(t) + \int_0^t f(s) \,\mathrm{d}s.
$$
I already showed that $T$ is a bounded linear operator with $\|T\|=2$.  The problem asks me to show that $T$ is injective.

What I tried was to show $\ker T = \{0\}$, which means the equation $Tf(t)=0$, or
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
f(t) + \int_0^t f(s) \,\mathrm{d}s = 0
\end{equation}
for all $t \in [0,1]$ has a unique solution $f \equiv 0$.  Differentiating both sides with respect to $t$ gives the ODE:
$$
f'(t) + f(t) = 0,
$$
which has a solution $f(t)=Ce^{-t}$, where $C$ is a constant.  Since equation $(1)$ gives $f(0)=0$, we must have $C=0$, and equation $Tf(t)=0$ has a solution $f \equiv 0$.

However, I'm not sure how to show $f = 0$ is the unique solution to $(1)$ (or maybe it must be from the general solution to the ODE).

I wonder if differentiation can be done in this case because $f$ is only continuous, not a $C^1$ function.

Is there other way to solve this problem like assuming $Tf = Tg$ and showing $f=g$ (I was stuck on this)?

Does it have something to do with the Hahn-Banach Theorem, (I don't know the space and the operator)?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you did everything correctly. The point is that $f(t) = c \cdot e^{-t}$ are the unique solutions to your ODE (for $c$ real).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kernel of $f\mapsto f + \int f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2641832/kernel-of-f-mapsto-f-int-f)

Comment: for the argument $T(f)=T(g)$ implies $f=g$ just apply the method you used before (the one with the kernel) for $h=f-g.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be shown that the operator $T$ is invertible and verified directly that the inverse is given by the formula
$$(T^{-1}f)(t)=f(t)-e^{t}\int\limits_0^te^{-s}f(s)\,ds$$ [see 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4743041/brezis-exercise-6-20-3-give-an-explicit-formula-for-t-lambda-i-1)
[see 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742866/brezis-exercise-6-20-2-prove-that-sigma-t-0/4743290#4743290). In particular the operator $T$ is injective

Comment: I really like your answer.  I thought about Banach fixed-point theorem before, but the integral operator wasn't a contraction on $[0,1]$.  You solved it.

Comment: I have modified the answer as the operator itself is invertible

Answer (score 5):

One important point is that (1) directly implies
$$
f(t) = -\int_0^t f(s) \, \mathrm d s,$$
i.e., $f$ is continuously differentiable, since the right-hand side is $C^1$ (fundamental theorem of calculus).